# Docker volume usage for storing jpg

Tags: laravel, docker, png, jpeg, docker-volume

So, i built a small application to test how docker works, is a small laravel app that registers users with its profile image. Everything is working properly but the profile image is not being display.

I assume this is because how docker works (ephemeral, unchange, etc), so i was reading a bit about volumes but unfortunately i was not able to make it work.

The images are stored inside a folder called uploads within public folder (laravel structure).

In my docker-compose.yml file i have the following volumes defined:

```
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
```

So i tried to add the one that i need, something like this:

```
    volumes:
      - mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
      - user-images:/app/public/uploads
    volumes:
      mysql-data:
      user-images:
```

I also tried with bind mounts but i think this can only be used using docker container run (not quite sure).

Any idea on how could i fix this?

Thanks

Comment: what is the permission on `user-images` directory ? share output of `ls -l user-images`

Comment: Hi, the permissions are  "drwxrwxr-x" for both public and uploads folder.

Comment: what is the ownership ? and are you running your application with different user inside container or root user ?

Comment: Sorry, the ownership inside the container is root:root. For running the container i use my username "angel".

Comment: `docker run -itd --name name-of-container -v host-dir:container-dir name-of-image` ? share the output of this command here replce whatever volumes you are using for like mysql-data, user-images

Comment: so are you starting your application with `root` or `angel` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user-images:/app/public/uploads` would be a *named* volume, defined in `/var/lib/docker/volumes`

If you want to use [a bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/), that is mounting an host folder as a volume, use a path:

```
volumes:
  - "./user-images:/app/public/uploads"
```

See also "[Laravel + Docker](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-1-setup-for-development-e3daaefaf3c)" and its [part 2](https://medium.com/@shakyShane/laravel-docker-part-2-preparing-for-production-9c6a024e9797) for a more complete example.

Comment: not working, i just add a file in `/app/public/uploads` , but its not showing up in `./user-images`, what happen?

Comment: @aswzen not sure, could you ask a separate question with more details for me or others to have a look?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your image is in directory tree with the dockerfile/docker-compose. If that is the case you actually don't want to use a named volume given those are stored elsewhere on your system and would require you move your image to that location. (see "Mountpoint" in image below)

[image]

What you likely want to use is the `--mount` flag which in your compose file would look like so...

```
volumes:
  - type: bind
    source: ./path/to/file
    target: /app/public/uploads
```

See docker [volumes](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#volumes) docks for more info. I wrote the long version which I prefer as it's more explicit but the sort version does the same thing. You should be aware that using a bind volume will overwrite any files you might of added to the actual image if they overlap. Tip this is handy when you have a hot reloading dev server as you can change your files locally and they be ran in the containers context.